# Getting error after calling a service in eloquent

Tags: slam, navigation, ros2, service, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I`m trying to use a Rtabmap service, which is defined as follows:

```
 #request
 bool global
 bool optimized
 bool graph_only
 ---
 #response
```

Then, I call:

```
 ros2 service call /publish_map rtabmap_ros/srv/PublishMap "{global: 1, optimized: 1, graph_only: 0}"
```

But it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/eloquent/bin/ros2", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ros2cli==0.8.7', 'console_scripts', 'ros2')()
File "/opt/ros/eloquent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ros2cli/cli.py", line 69, in main
    rc = extension.main(parser=parser, args=args)
File "/opt/ros/eloquent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ros2service/command/service.py", line 43, in main
    return extension.main(args=args)
File "/opt/ros/eloquent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ros2service/verb/call.py", line 59, in main
    args.service_type, args.service_name, args.values, period)
File "/opt/ros/eloquent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ros2service/verb/call.py", line 69, in requester
    module = importlib.import_module('.'.join(parts[:-1]))
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/user/rtabmap_ros/install/rtabmap_ros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rtabmap_ros/srv/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from rtabmap_ros.srv._get_map import GetMap  # noqa: F401
File "/home/user/rtabmap_ros/install/rtabmap_ros/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rtabmap_ros/srv/_get_map.py", line 77
    self.global = kwargs.get('global', bool())
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please, any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366860/getting-error-after-calling-a-service-in-eloquent/) by [mirella melo](https://answers.ros.org/users/55539/mirella-melo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 194 on 2020-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, the problem here seems to be the field name `global` used in the service definition. I could not find any ROS2 resource for this, but the [ROS1 msg wiki](https://wiki.ros.org/msg#Field_Names) said:

> It is recommended that you avoid using field names that correspond to keywords in common languages -- although those names are legal, they create confusion as to how a field name is translated.

This seems to be exactly what is happening here. The ROS2 cli packages are written in python (this wasn't the case in ROS1), and `global` is a keyword in python. So IMO this looks like an issue in the `rtabmap_ros` package.

---

Originally posted by [RobertWilbrandt](https://answers.ros.org/users/64579/robertwilbrandt/) with karma: 176 on 2020-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mirella melo](https://answers.ros.org/users/55539/mirella-melo/) on 2020-12-03**:
This makes sense! Hopefully, the Rtabmap team will fix it if this is the case. Thank you for your reply!!